# show time on hover in full calendar vertical resource view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I wants to display the corresponding time on hovering over each cell in full calendar vertical resource view. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the following link,

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/102